# Change array of objects with array inside, to one object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, with another array inside them, and I want to convert the bigger array to one object like so:

```
[{
name: "test"
options: [
0: {id: "1", value: ""}
1: {id: "2", value: ""}
2: {id: "3", value: ""}
3: {id: "4", value: ""}]
}]
```

I want the final result to be like this:

```
{
  test: [
    {id: "1", value: ""},
    {id: "2", value: ""},
    {id: "3", value: ""},
    {id: "4", value: ""}
  ]
}
```

What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Please share the code that you have written attempting to solve your problem and ask a specific question. Hint: "I want" is not a question 

Comment: The question is how would I do that? I did not write any code

Comment: Then maybe try first? Or show us how you approached the problem so far.

Comment: What does `options: Array[]` mean?

Comment: It is not even valid object

Comment: Please post a realistic example. You said, you've got an array of objects. Your array has only one object in it.

Comment: `{ [data[0].name]: data[0].options };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` for object creation

`reduce` takes a function as an argument and this function can take several arguments (at least 2), first is called an `accumulator`, it contains all sum of all previous calls of this function and the second argument is `current`, it contains a current value, in this case current object which we want to transform. As you can see, there is a `{}` in the end of `reduce` and this is `initialValue` which means that at first run of that function which is inside `reduce`, `accumulator` will be this value, so `{}` (empty object)

```js
var arr = [
  {
    name: "test",
    options: [
      {id: "1", value: ""},
      {id: "2", value: ""},
      {id: "3", value: ""},
      {id: "4", value: ""}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    options: [
      {id: "12", value: ""},
      {id: "23", value: ""},
      {id: "34", value: ""},
      {id: "45", value: ""}
    ]
  }
]

var obj = arr.reduce((obj1, { name, options }) => ({...obj1, [name]: options}), {})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: with ES6: `arr = arr.map(({ name, options }) => ({ [name]: options }));`

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it is still wrapped by an array :(

Comment: Oh I see, you want only object, I will fix it

Comment: I want  just the value to be an array, and the key as the name. {  key: array , key, array  }

Comment: Thanks @Thomas for a hint

Comment: Oh, now I get it, I will edit an answer

Comment: @Malinki please check it now

Comment: Thank you very much :) I need to read about reduce, didn't a very good idea on how to use

Comment: I will edit it and add an explanation of it :) Glad to help