# Unable to convert a nested object into an array of objects and viceversa

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am having an object of the following kind:

```
var sourceObj = {
                   "feature1": [
                                 {"id":"1","name":"abc","enabled":false,"type":"type1"},
                                 {"id":"2","name":"xyz","enabled":false,"type":"type1"}
                                ]
                   ,
                   "feature2": [
                                  {"id":"3","name":"lmn","enabled":true,"type":"type2"},
                                  {"id":"4","name":"pqr","enabled":false,"type":"type2"}
                                ]
                }
```

Need to get converted to an array of objects of the following type:

```
var destArr =  [
                  { "feature_name":"feature1", 
                    "feature_details":[
                                        {"id":"1","name":"abc","enabled":false,"type":"type1"},
                                        {"id":"2","name":"xyz","enabled":true,"type":"type1"}
                                      ]
                  },
                  { "feature_name":"feature2",
                    "feature_details":[
                                        {"id":"3","name":"lmn","enabled":true,"type":"type2"}
                                        {"id":"4","name":"pqr","enabled":false,"type":"type2"}
                                      ]
                  } 
              ]
```

I have tried the following approaches for conversion of source object to resultant array of objects and resultant array of objects back to the source object

```
//Converting source object to array of objects
let arr = Object.keys(sourceObj).map(key => {
    return sourceObj[key];
  })


converting array of objects back to source objetc
let obj = Object.assign({}, ...destArr.map(item => ({ [item.name]: item.value })));
```

Comment: I did something similar here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608261/change-array-of-objects-with-array-inside-to-one-object/57608461#57608461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Object.entries` to map everything in a single shot.
To go back to the original structure, you could use `reduce` against the generated array (see `backToOriginalArray` below)

```js
var sourceObj = {
    "feature1": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "abc",
            "enabled": false,
            "type": "type1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "xyz",
            "enabled": false,
            "type": "type1"
        }
    ],
    "feature2": [{
            "id": "3",
            "name": "lmn",
            "enabled": true,
            "type": "type2"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "pqr",
            "enabled": false,
            "type": "type2"
        }
    ]
};

// Step 1: use object.entries against the original object to build an array of objects.
var destArray = Object.entries(sourceObj).map(([key, value]) => ({
    "feature_name": key,
    "feature_details": value
}));
console.log(destArray);

// Step 2: use reduce against the generated array to get an object with the same structure of the original one.
var backToOriginalArray = destArray.reduce((acc, {feature_name, feature_details}) => (acc[feature_name] = feature_details, acc), {});
console.log(backToOriginalArray);
```

Comment: Also resultant of your array of objects back to the source object?

Comment: @vjr I didn't understand your question. You want a way to go back to the original object?

Answer (score 1):

Map the `Object.entries` of your initial object:

```js
var sourceObj = {
  "feature1": [
    {"id":"1","name":"abc","enabled":false,"type":"type1"},
    {"id":"2","name":"xyz","enabled":false,"type":"type1"}
  ],
  "feature2": [
    {"id":"3","name":"lmn","enabled":true,"type":"type2"},
    {"id":"4","name":"pqr","enabled":false,"type":"type2"}
  ]
};

const destArr = Object.entries(sourceObj).map(
  ([feature_name, feature_details]) => ({ feature_name, feature_details })
);
console.log(destArr);
```

To go the other way around, use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const arr=[{feature_name:"feature1",feature_details:[{id:"1",name:"abc",enabled:!1,type:"type1"},{id:"2",name:"xyz",enabled:!1,type:"type1"}]},{feature_name:"feature2",feature_details:[{id:"3",name:"lmn",enabled:!0,type:"type2"},{id:"4",name:"pqr",enabled:!1,type:"type2"}]}];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(
  ({ feature_name, feature_details }) => [feature_name, feature_details]
));
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Also resultant of your array of objects back to the source object?

Comment: Use `Object.fromEntries`